# Why is the volume coming from -80db to 0 - not even starting at 0?

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, decibel

I'm very new to sound. I've never explored this area in my whole life.

I thought decibels was a measure starting at 0.
But in Unity, it starts at `-80db` and and "`0db`" it seems it's the "100%" level volume.

[image: Unity AudioMixer group]

Moreover, when I change the sound to `-40db` it's not "half-way" between `-80db` and and `0` it seems it's much closer to `-80db`. So the user hears nothing when it's "half-way":
[image: half-way sound selection]

I couldn't find anywhere how to setup sound properly, and how to make the user choose "properly" the sound (= good scale).

Any idea / Unity valuable sample for this?

Comment: dB is a logarithmic scale: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia -> Decibel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel)

> dB is a **relative** unit of measurement [...] It expresses the **ratio** of two values

This is very common for Audio Mixers and Amps that `0` means 100% of the configured `Pre-Gain` (-> in this case the input volume of your individual AudioSources).

**Why?** -> The given `dB` are just the **additional** "multiplicator" (as said it is a **logarithmic ratio** between two values).

Usually as an Audio manager you first configure all `Pre-Gains` in a way that basically everything has more or less the same absolute volume if all mixer sliders are at `0`.

Then you start to actually **mix** them according to your needs and only move certain volumes up or down to increase or decrease the volume by a certain factor. (Except for fading it is usually pretty uncommon to actually pull a slider down to the minimum - usually you rather `Mute` the channel)

- `0dB` just means `1:1` => Don't change.
- e.g. `6dB` means about `2:1` => twice as loud as the input volume
- e.g. `-6dB` means about `1:2` => half as loud as the input volume
- e.g. `20dB` means about `10:1` => Ten times as loud as the input volume
- e.g. `-80dB` means `1:10000` => So `0.0001` of the input volume

So the `-80` is chosen a little bit arbitrary .. it could as well be `-60` (=>factor of `0.001`) or `-100` (=> factor of `0.00001`). "It doesn't really matter!". At a certain point the volume is simply so low that you won't hear it anymore depending on what the default maximum output of your Amp is and how precise you need the output to be.

You can e.g. use [this dB calculator](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-db.htm) to check what `dB` value results in what actual factor.

For a better explanation of the `dB` measure itself see also e.g. [these posts](https://www.quora.com/In-sound-measurement-0-dB-is-the-threshold-of-hearing-but-why-in-digital-audio-mixers-or-in-amplifiers-0-dB-is-referred-as-Maximum-loudness) and [What's the minimum decibel value?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69668/whats-the-minimum-decibel-value)